# Exception while calling a webservice which accepts xml file as object

Tags: xml, web-services

I need to call a third party web service which accepts xml file as object.

```
-<Claims>
  -<Claim>
      <ID>ID1</ID>
       -<Person>
           <ID>ID1</ID>
        </Person>
       -<Encounter>
           <Type>1</Type>
        </Encounter>
        -<Diagnosis>
            <CodeTerm>ICD10</CodeTerm>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Code>A12.0</Code>
         </Diagnosis>
        -<Activity>
            <ID>ID1</ID>
            <CodeTerm>ADA</CodeTerm>
            <Start>12/02/2013 12:12</Start>
            <Code>84132</Code>
            <Quantity>0</Quantity>
         </Activity>
     </Claim>
</Claims>
```

I have created a sample class and hardcoded the value. Getting the below Exception while calling the webservice.

```
**System.InvalidOperationException**
Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.
Message: **The type CallingWebserviceTest.Claims was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.**

Code:



     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

                    Claims c = new Claims();
                    List<ClaimsClaim> c1 = new List<ClaimsClaim>();
                    ClaimsClaim cc = new ClaimsClaim();
                    cc.claimID = "ID1";
                    cc.personID = "ID1";
                    cc.encounterType = 1;
                    cc.codeTerm = "ICD10";
                    cc.codeType = "A12.0";
                    cc.activityID = "ID1";
                    cc.codeTerm = "ADA";
                    cc.start = "12/02/2013 12:12";
                    cc.activityCode = 84132;
                    cc.quantity = 0;
                    c1.Add(cc);
                    c.claims = c1;
                    Console.WriteLine(cc.personID);               
                    Gway g = new Gway();
                    responseClaimEdit[] responce;
                    string msg;


    Console.WriteLine(g.DCG("1", c, "NS028", "|N28", out responce, out msg).ToString());

Class:

     [XmlInclude(typeof(ClaimsClaim))]
        [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot]
        public class Claims
        {
            public List<ClaimsClaim> claims { get; set; }

        }


        [Serializable]
        public class ClaimsClaim
        {
            public string claimID { get; set; }
            public string personID { get; set; }
            public int encounterType { get; set; }
            public string codeTerm { get; set; }
            public string codeType { get; set; }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public string activityID { get; set; }
            public string activityCodeTerm { get; set; }
            public string start { get; set; }
            public int activityCode { get; set; }
            public int quantity { get; set; }           
        }
```

Can anyone please help here? No change can be done in the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the XDocument class expects the XML file to have a standard XML header such as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: I am not sure, have to contact the service provider. However can u plz tell me how to pass this- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Yes I understand, but how to add this in my class?

Comment: Normally, the line I mentioned would be the very first line in a standard XML file. Some class libraries will process an XML file without this line but some of them won't process and will require it.

You can do a simple test by inserting this line at the beginning of the file and re-running your application to see if it makes a difference.

Also, looking at the error message, `CallingWebserviceTest.Claims was not expected` seems like the calling client application doesn't know what the Claims class is. That's just a guess though but that may also be an issue.

Comment: How would you add it to the class? You would add it with XDocument like this example:

var doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"), 
            new XElement("Elem1", "Elem2"));